# Create a model with non-DAG relationship

Tags: causality

I want to model the relationship between time spent watching video ads and purchases. There is a correlation between viewing time and purchase. The longer the viewing time, the higher the purchase intent; and the higher the purchase intent, the longer the viewing time. How can we model such a non-DAG (feedback) relationship to know the impact of the two factors on both parties?

Comment: "The longer the viewing time, the higher the purchase intent, and the longer the viewing time, ..." You said the same thing twice? Also, not at all clear how this is a non-DAG relationship. If $A$ causes $B,$ no matter what the functional relationship, we can draw $A\to B.$

Comment: I think "The longer the viewing time, the higher the purchase intent, and the longer the viewing time, the higher the purchase intent. " was meant to be "The longer the viewing time, the highr the purchase intent, and the higher the purchase intent, the longer the viewing time."

Comment: These kind of chicken-egg arguments in statistics can only hope to be addressed with very complicated longitudinal models. Scenarios like these may often begin with something simple like a Markov model. Even then, what's the appropriate time interval? Calendar time? Or "arrival times" for events of purchasing and ad viewing?

Comment: @AdamO Viewing time is defined as the time from the beginning to the end of viewing the video recorded in the log data. The time between the end of the viewing and the purchase is not taken into account at this time

Comment: @AdrianKeister :I typed incorrectly, and as Adam says, "The longer the viewing time, the higher the purchase intent, and the higher the purchase intent, the longer the viewing time." is correct.

Comment: So you have a feedback loop? Is that what you're saying? $VT(t)\to PI(t)$ and $PI(t)\to VT(t+1)?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, I assume so (although PI is difficult to measure directly.)

Comment: I think @AdamO is correct: start with a Markov chain and see where that leads you.